# What's the crawled or managed property name for the "Description" field in the site pages library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, modern-experience, pnp

The Description field is the summary or excerpt that displays in news feeds for news post type site pages.

I've searched crawled and managed properties at `/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx` and tried to map all that show up but still description doesn't show up in the search results using a custom layout with a handlebars template in the PnP modern search app.

Comment: Did you try using these two managed properties: `Description` and `DescriptionOWSMTXT`?

Comment: "Description" didn't work but the other one did, so thanks! Documentation on this is appalling.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Do you know what the managed property is for the _AuthorByline field? I've trried everything I could find but none work so far.

Comment: @GaneshSanap AuthorOWSUSER works but gives me the "created by" value not author byline. And gives all the values of a people field. I just want lastname, firstname. I tried AuthorOWSUSER.title but that doesn't work (in a handlebars template).

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Yes, "AuthorOWSUSER" property is associated with SP default "Created By" field. I will investigate for author by line field & get back to you shortly.

Comment: Crawled property for Autor Byline is `ows_q_USER__AuthorByline`. Try mapping it with one of the managed property (existing or create a new managed property) & check if it works. Also, try using "PostAuthor" managed property.

Comment: The "ows_q_..." seems to be it but it returns an array - I just need last name, first name part: It returns:  xxx@xxx.com | lastname, firstname | xxxx32323837314076657269736B2E636F6D i:0#.f|membership|ixxx@xxx.com

Comment: Try mapping this crawled property once `ows__AuthorByline`. If it does not work for you, you have to use `ows_q_USER__AuthorByline` and split the result to get only last name, first name.

Comment: That didn't work. I found "DisplayAuthor" works but replaces author byline with created by if there's no author byline specified which isn't good. I'll try your split idea...

Comment: Sure, check if this helps: [Persona filters](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/v3/search-parts/search-filters/#persona) and [Register Handlebars customizations](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/extensibility/handlebars_customizations/). If more help needed, please ask a new question on this forum so that others will also contribute on it.

Answer (score 1):

Managed property name for the "Description" field in the site pages library is "DescriptionOWSMTXT".

So, try using "DescriptionOWSMTXT" in your search configurations.